# How to create a fitted data frame for GAMs?

Tags: r, dataframe, gam

I am trying to build a map out of a GAM and I am unable to create a fitted data frame. Below is my code. Happy to provide any additional information if needed. Thank you!

```
library(mgcv)
AreaNmod <- gam(data=df_all, formula=find15N.1 ~ s(lat, lon, by = area, k = 10) + area, method = "REML")
summary(AreaNmod)
AIC (AreaNmod)
plot(AreaNmod)

df_05_dis_NoNA <- df_05_dis[is.na(df_05_dis),]

fitted_df <- data.frame(predict(AreaNmod,se.fit = TRUE, newdata = df_05_dis_NoNA))

Error in X[, pstart[i] - 1 + 1:object$nsdf[i]] <- Xp :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.gam(AreaNmod, se.fit = TRUE, newdata = df_05_dis_NoNA) :
factor levels MAB not in original fit
```

I attempted to adjust the lengths of the dataframe but still received the same errors. Any advice?

Comment: According to the error message, your new prediction data (`df_05_dis_NoNA`) contains factor levels which did not appear in `AReaNmod`, so the model trained without these levels does not know what (which prediction) to make of them.